# Spring REST MVC: validation of incoming XML (without using form)

Tags: xml, spring, rest, validation

I have a controller that receives as @RequestBody a string containing a request XML.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/app-authorization")
public Response getAppAuthorization(
        HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult results,
        @RequestBody String body){
    log.info("Requested app-authorization through xml: \n" + body);

    Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(body));
    RefreshTokenRequest req = (RefreshTokenRequest) jaxb2Mashaller.unmarshal(source);

    validator.validate(req, results);
    if(results.hasErrors()){
        log.info("DOESN'T WORK!");
        response.setStatus(500);
        return null;
    }
    InternalMessage<Integer, Response> auth = authService.getRefreshToken(req);
    response.setStatus(auth.getHttpStatus());
    return auth.getReponse();
}
```

The AuthorizationValidator is the following:

```
@Component("authenticationValidator")
public class AuthenticationValidator implements Validator{

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return AuthorizationRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        errors.rejectValue("test", "there are some errors");

    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to inject an object Validator into my controller in such a way that:

1. @Autowired \n Validator validator; makes me obtain automatically a reference to my AuthenticationValidator
2. every controller is linked to one or more validators withouth indicating their class explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of what  you are doing manually can be completely handled by Spring MVC, you should be able to get your method to this structure:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/app-authorization")
public Response getAppAuthorization(@Valid @RequestBody RefreshTokenRequest req, BindingResult results){

    if(results.hasErrors()){
        log.info("DOESN'T WORK!");
        response.setStatus(500);
        return null;
    }
    InternalMessage<Integer, Response> auth = authService.getRefreshToken(req);
    response.setStatus(auth.getHttpStatus());
    return auth.getReponse();
}
```

with Spring MVC taking care of calling JAXB unmarshaller and `@Valid` annotation on the type taking care of the validation.

Now to register a custom validator for your types, you can do this:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(this.authenticationValidator );
}
```

If you want to set it globally instead of for a specific controller, you can create your custom global validator, internally delegating to other validators, for eg:

```
public class CustomGlobalValidator implements Validator {

    @Resource private List<Validator> validators;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        for (Validator validator: validators){
            if (validator.supports(clazz)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        //find validator supporting class of obj, and delegate to it

    }
}
```

and register this global Validator:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="globalValidator"/>
```